# Can a queue subscribe(listen) to another queue in rabbit mq

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

We have 2 rabbitmq brokers.

we publish to queue A of Broker1, can the queue B of Broker2 subscribe directly to queue A so that no latency is there, as incase of writing the handler for it(using @rabbitListener) and then publishing to another queue.

My question is can the Broker2 directly subscribe to broker1 with any rabit handler or Can broker2(another queue) consume the data of queue in broker1 directly ? Is it possible ?

If yes how to achieve it through spring-amqp  ?

Note : Two RabbitMq brokers in the sense 2 different rabbitmq servers

Comment: Do you want to just move the message from Broker 1 to Broker 2 or do you want to do any processing in between? A queue cannot subscribe to another queue in `RabbitMQ`

Comment: Just move it to broker 2, no processing involved.

Answer (score 2):

We have the concept of queue federation, where queues transmit messages to other queues. The main purpose of a federated queue is to balance load across RabbitMQ brokers. Here consumers will be connected to downstream queue and consumes messages from it, once downstream queue is empty and when the consumer tries to consume messages from downstream queues, the messages from upstream queue will be transmitted to downstream queue to satisfy the need of the consumer.
Here notice that messages are transmitted to downstream queue only on demand, if consumer is not demanding for messages, then the messages will not be transmitted to downstream.

Federation has major advantages over using clusters.

Answer (score 0):

- You can't publish to a *queue*, you can only publish to an *exchange*.
- Queues can be bound to exchanges but not to queues inside a single RabbitMQ instance.
- To move messages from queue A to broker 2 you will have to implement some small application that consumes messages from queue A and publishes them to an exchange on broker 2.

Answer (score 0):

A `queue` cannot consume from another queue. The unit of work in `RabbitMQ` is the `consumer`. There are tow ways by which your problem can be solved:

**Solution 1**: 
Create a cluster of RabbitMQ servers with both of your servers. Use a fanout exchange to route the same message to both the queues.

**Solution 2**:
Create a consumer that consumes from queue1 and re-queue the same message to both queue1 and queue2.

If you want messages to be present in both the queues follow **solution 1**. If you want to move the message(not copy) follow **solution 2**.

Hope this helps!.

Comment: Thanks for the input . But isnt the exchange tied up to server. ? 
Will the fanout exchange be able to route the message to different server as well ??

Comment: Yes, if you maintain a cluster of `RabbitMQ` servers.